# С++ Лёгкая задача

Tags: c++

Как при выводе cout<< mas2d[j][i]<<" "; не ставить пробел после каждого числа, к примеру после первых двух выводить, а после последнего числа нет

Вот код (надо перевернуть матрицу)
Отрывок кода

```
   cout<< mas2d[j][i]<<" ";

   cout<<endl;
```

return 0;

---

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
using namespace std; 

int main() { 
  int mas2d[3][3]; 
  int a; 
  cin>>a; 

  for(int j=0;j<3;j++) 
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++) 
      cin>>mas2d[i][j]; 

  for(int j=0;j<3;j++) { 
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++) 
      cout<<mas2d[j][i]<<" "; 
    cout<<endl; 
  }
  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Мне нужно сделать так чтобы пробел не вывелся после последнего числа

Answer (score 2):

```
// i - from 0 to k - 1
cout << mas2d[j][i] << ((i == (k - 1))? "" : " ");
```

---

```
  for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) { 
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
      cout << mas2d[j][i] << ((i == 2)? "" : " "); 
    cout << endl; 
  }
```

Comment: извините но это не работает

Comment: @Limpopo Это работает для того кода, который я вообразил у себя в голове, так как в вопросе кода недостаточно.

Comment: #include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int mas2d[3][3];
   int a;
    cin>>a;
   for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
   cin>>mas2d[i][j];

   for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
   {
       for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
       cout<<mas2d[j][i]<<" ";

       cout<<endl;
   }
return 0;
}